# How to add element at the end of linked list along with at position with different code for them?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, insert

So, i tried doing inserting at the end of linked list and at given position have different code. I know there is another way round but i want to know why can't i do it this way.
here's my code:-

```
        SinglyLinkedListNode *temp=head,*head2=head;
        int count=0;
        while(temp->next!=NULL){
            if(count==position){
                newnode->next=temp;
                head2->next=newnode;
                return head;
                break;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
            count++;
        }
        count++;
        if(count==position){
            temp->next=newnode;
        }
```

with this code the elements get inserted at the beginning fine but they won't add at the position:-

Your Output (stdout)

16 13 7

Expected Output

16 13 1 7

edit:-
it doesnt work even after i changed temp=head. It wont add elements to the list.

Comment: `SinglyLinkedListNode *temp,*head2=head;` here `temp` is not initialized, but then you dereference it

Comment: ohh! yeah! but still it's not adding elements

Comment: [Edit] and show a [MCVE]

Comment: yeah ...i edited but ...found the mistake. I was not considering the case when last element have to be replaced...

Answer (score 1):

you have not point temp to head in line, head2 is pointing but not temp

> SinglyLinkedListNode *temp,*head2=head;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I could find out what went wrong ...I was not considering the case when the last element have to be replaced.

The solution is :-

```
        SinglyLinkedListNode *temp=head,*head2=head;
        int count=0;
        while(temp->next!=NULL){
            
            if(count==position){
                newnode->next=temp;
                head2->next=newnode;
                return head;
                break;
            }
            count++;
            head2=temp; //cout<<count<<' '<<position;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        if(count==position){
            newnode->next=temp;
            head2->next=newnode;
        }//cout<<head2->data;
        count++;
        if(count==position){
            temp->next=newnode;
        }
```